# Palindrome program using stack and queue

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program to determine if a user-entered string of characters is a palindrome through the use of a stack and queue.

When I go to compile the program, the program successfully compiles.  However, when I execute the program, I type in a string of characters to test if it is a palindrome and then the program's cursor blinks and I must cancel the program or the execution appears to pause on the screen.  I have never encountered this issue before.

I used cout statements to determine where the issue begins and determined that the issue begins at the last if statement.

I found numerous examples from other individuals about palindrome C++ program's and attempted to compare mine, but I am having no luck after a few hours.

May you please explain why the issue that I described is occurring?
I appreciate any help that you may be able to provide!  Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    #include "Stack.h"
    #include "Queue.h"

    int main (void)
    {
      Stack s;
      Queue q;
      string letter;
      int length;
      int notmatch;
      notmatch=0;

      cout<<"Please enter a series of characters."<<endl;
      cin>>letter;
      length = letter.size();

      for (int i=1; i <= length; i++)
        {
          q.enqueue(i);
          s.push(i);
        }

       while ((!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
        {
          if (s.top() != q.front() )
             {
               notmatch++;
               q.dequeue();
               s.pop();
              }
        }

      if (notmatch == 0)
        {
          cout<<"The entered series of characters is a palindrome."<<endl;
        }
      else
        {
          cout<<"The entered series of characters is not a palindrome."<<endl;
        }
    }
```

So based on my understanding of the comments that I received (Thank you!), I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"

int main (void)
{
  Stack s;
  Queue q;
  string letter;
  int length;

  cout<<"Please enter a series of characters."<<endl;
  cin>>letter;
  length = letter.size();

  for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
      q.enqueue(i);
      s.push(i);
    }

     bool isPalindrome = true;
     while (isPalindrome && (!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
     {
       if (s.top() != q.front() )
        {
          isPalindrome = false;
        }
      else
       {
        q.dequeue();
        s.pop();
        }
    }

  if(isPalindrome == false)
   {
     cout<<"Not a palindrome."<<endl;
   }
  else
   {
     cout<<"Is a palindrome."<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: In cases where if 1 single mismatch is considered failure, you should not continue on your first failure. Here you are looping even after `s.top() != q.front()` is `true`.

Comment: @Jagannath also if that condition is false, it enters an infinite loop if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Ok. I am beginning to understand what you mean I think.  So I will need to create an else statement? Thank you for your quick response! @Jagannath

Comment: You also store consecutive numbers in Your queue and stack. This way You'll never get a positive result. If You want to store chars from string You also need to go from `i=0` when `i<length`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
while ((!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
{
    if (s.top() != q.front() )
    {
        notmatch++;
        q.dequeue();
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

if the condition inside the `if` statement is true(which means is not a palindrome) you shouldn't keep looping as pointed out by @Jagannath, on the other hand if the condition is false(which means it could be a palindrome) then nothing happens so your stack and queue aren't empty and that causes an infinite loop, that's why you need to kill the program.

I believe this should stop the endless loop:

```
bool isPalindrome = true;
while (isPalindrome && (!q.empty()) && (!s.empty()))
{
    if (s.top() != q.front() )
    {
        isPalindrome = false;
    }
    else
    {
        q.dequeue();
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So in order to fix the first part, I would do:                                                                            if (s.top() != q.front())                                                                                              {   cout<<"Not a palindrome."<<endl;                                                                                                                                                                                           }                                                                                                                              Correct??

Comment: @jvi1021 that would still leave the loop running

Comment: Is that because of the use of the while loop? @Alejandro Diaz

Comment: @jvi1021 well yeah, the loop will keep running until the condition is false, or you use `break`

Comment: So in order to fix that without the use of break, I would remove the while loop completely and use if/else? I did so to see what would happen and all entered characters appear to not be palindromes even if they are...

Comment: @jvi1021 You still need the loop, you need to check every character until a)you find characters that are different so you can assure that the word isn't a palindrome or b)you checked all characters, also check riodoro1's comment

Comment: Ok.  So I added the while loop back in. I cannot use break. Taking this one thing at a time, I need to find characters that are different...so I would state inside of the while loop that when the front of the queue and the top of the stack are not equal then the word is not a palindrome...so when I do that I get an end-less loop. I am not sure how to fix that...

Comment: Thank you!! The endless loop did stop with that.  I used if/else statements to print out if it is or is not a palindrome, but everything appears to not be a palindrome even if it is.  I read the comments is from riodoro1's and did change i to 0.  I posted updated code above. @Alejandro Diaz